# How to solve git [ERROR] Invalid syntax in configuration ini file

Tags: git, commit, ini

I'm trying to commit some changes with git but, when I do it, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Invalid syntax in configuration ini file.

Couldn't find any information about it, anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: This message does not come from Git. Look at your installed hooks (in your `.git/hooks` directory) and see which one of those is generating the error. That's what you need to fix, not Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try commiting with the `-n (--no-verify)` flags

Comment: This worked for me! Does anyone know what the root cause of this issue is though?

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is Windows, search for the git-template and config folders inside your user folder and check if they have a security-tools folder inside it.
You will need to manually add the folders with their contents if they are empty.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked deleting all files inside hooks folder, <your_project_directoty>/.git/hooks/

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, this is bad advice. Renaming it would certainly be safer; then if it doesn't help, restoring it is easy. If there's a bad hook, identifying and fixing that particular file is a vasty better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have nested .git folders in my project. leaving the one in root folder of my project and removing the nested .git folders resolves my issue